# How can I get the CentOS boot progress bar in Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, plymouth

CentOS / RedHat Linux comes with a very simple but nice text mode boot progress bar (see image). Does Ubuntu 20.04 have an equivalent (or text mode splash screens at all, for that matter), and if so, what commands can I run to install & enable it?
Edit: I'm using Ubuntu server 20.04, no gui. My attempts at using plymouth haven't gone well, it seems to be extremely skewed towards graphical boot splashes, text ones don't even show up for me on the "update-alternatives --config default.plymouth" list. I do have plymouth-themes and plymouth-labels installed, if that affects anything.

[image: CentOS Boot Progress Bar]

Comment: Check out `plymouth`.

Comment: So far, plymouth seems very skewed towards graphical splash screens, I can't even get text ones to show up on the "update-alternatives --config default.plymouth" list. (I do have plymouth-themes and plymouth-labels installed, in case that affects anything.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install grub breeze theme:

```
sudo apt-get install grub-theme-breeze
```

2. Next, run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

3. Finally, reboot.